# Authlib ConnectTimeout from HTTPX with Starlette OAuth Client

Tags: authlib

I have a *known* issue where DNS resolution is causing timeouts when attempting to authorize the access token. The Starlette OAuth Client relies on HTTPX for async requests, and HTTPX has a known timeout of 5 seconds.

Is there a way for me to configure Authlib's OAuth Client to have a *longer* timeout than the 5 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to figure this out, anything you specify in `client_kwargs` in the `register` function will get passed to the HTTPX client. So, using this configuration worked for me:

```py
# Setup Google OAuth
oauth = OAuth(config.local_config)
oauth.register(
    name="google",
    server_metadata_url="https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration",
    authorize_params={"hd": config.FORCED_AUTHENTICATION_DOMAIN, "access_type": "offline"},
    client_kwargs={"scope": "openid email profile", "timeout": Timeout(timeout=config.AUTHENTICATION_TIMEOUT)},
)
```